# Rejecting Ajax JSON based post with html

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When using JQuery's $.Ajax(..) to post a JSON object containing markup to an MVC action method, I was surprised to learn that the content isn't rejected by ASP.Net's request validation.

Is there a reason why the request validation isn't applied to JSON posts?

With the following definition, markup is not rejected by the server...

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/Controller/Action',
        data: JSON.stringify({data:data}),
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
      });
```

Seems like it's tied to posts of type JSON

I am using .Net 4.0 MVC 3.0

I am creating functionality to save comments to a database. Seems like a security issue that markup/scripts can make it past the request validation...

I am posting a JSON object with various properties (e.g. commentText)
For some reason it's not rejecting my post if it contains markup like `<div></div>` etc

Found an article here that seems to explain the behavior:

http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/05/23/security-issue-in-asp-net-mvc3-jsonvalueproviderfactory.aspx

Comment: Could you tell which version of ASP.NET you are using? Because request validation has changed in 4.0.

Comment: Updated question. I am using .Net 4.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be a clue here
http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/05/23/security-issue-in-asp-net-mvc3-jsonvalueproviderfactory.aspx

Comment: This is not an answer, just an observation of the fact and a suggestion for mitigation. The question why application/json is not subject to ASP.NET RequestValidation is unanswered.

Comment: @Andreas, your comment definitely doesn't get me closer to the answer. Save your policing and suggest something that will help.

Comment: Hi @Brian, my intention was to get TGH to open up the question again since I am interested in the actual answer. I realize I could have expressed that intention better (and directed it at TGH). Sorry for sounding policing, I'd hate to come across as that kind of SO user.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're talking about request validation? It's on in MVC, so your JSON string must not be deemed as a threat by asp.net - I can't remember if it would by default reject a json string that contains markup, I suspect not though.

More info about it here: http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/02/19/understanding-request-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how exactly the data you pass to the server looks like, but right now I assume that it is just a plain string value 'xyz'. In this case the server gets the following POST data:

> {"data":"test"}

This is perfectly ok and does not represent a potential thread identified by ASP.NET.

PS: If you are using other values as data the whole story might be different...

Comment: Yes, it's a JSON object that contain smarkup like <div></div>

Answer (score 0):

Request validation works in Model using Data Annotation. You can enable and disable HTML makeup input in model. You can use [AllowHtml] to do that in your model. After that if a user input HTML in any normal field then you can check the error using Model.IsValid property.